# Align image to the top with "match_parent"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I've got a problem with my application. I've a image which goes across the whole screen (ImageView) with this code in xml:

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/achtergrond"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

My problem is that the image is centered in the imageview itself. It needs to be centered up as you can see in the next picture:

[image]
The left image is what I have, with the image in the middle. The right is what I want, the image should be up in the whole layout, I need to set my image to match_parent to have it fill as background (I didn't set it as background because it would be stretched then).

I hope I'm missing something obvious! Thanks for helping me in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/achtergrond"
    android:scaleType="fitStart" />
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it would be something simple!

Comment: I had to wait before I had the chance to accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I've still got one question. Now on a different device the image is centering on the left, and I need it on the right. Is there also a simple way to put it on the top and the right?

Comment: No. Fit Start aligns the image to top-left of your imageview. A better way to do that would be to set layout_height = "<your image height>" and scaleType = "fitXY".
 Since you are not putting anything on the below the image view the remaining part of your activity can reside below that image view, instead of the image view covering a whole empty space at the bottome.

Comment: I can't do that, because I'm running my application on different screen sizes. And it needs to be in the same scale. That's why I can't do it at the top-left. Isn't there a way to edit it via code ( I would prefer by XML, but maybe it's possible)?

Comment: if you put the image height in dp it will scale properly for different devices... for specific cases you can maintain different sizes in values folders

Comment: I know I can do that, but when I do it's changing the scale it's now at. I can't let that happen. Isn't there a way to set it use fitStart on the topRight?

Comment: No. ImageView ScaleTypes are very rigid in that respect.